# "No API environment is registered for this thread" error when persisting object to app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

I'm having some problem persisting object with my GWT-App engine project which I use Objectify for object persistence. However I am getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is
>   registered for this thread.

Based on the stack trace the error originated from the Objectify's `put` method. I have check that the object the application that is to be persisted is not NULL.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Could it be related to the pojo field, specifically the id? Because I have set the @Id to be Long however the getter and setter is set to String like:  public String getId() {
  return id.toString();
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = Long.valueOf(id); 
 }

Comment: Also I have created a new demo GWT-App engine project and copied the VM arguments, just to check whether if the problem is with the "Run Configuration"

Comment: Are you sharing an Objectify instance (e.g. a static member) between threads? You should always use ObjectifyService.begin() for each thread.

Comment: Riley's guess is a good one.  Either that or you're trying to run test cases without setting up the local api proxy.  You haven't set up the GAE environment in whatever context you are running.

Comment: ***Posted by @[Peter Martin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2656844/peter-martin) as an answer:*** I'm having the same problem, but ONLY when I run the development server with option "-server :ssl" to test my https oauth callbacks. When I run just simple http, no problem. When I run either http or https on my deployed app at xxx.appspot.com, no problem. There seems to be something funny happening with Objectify 4 and https on the development server. Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [ObjectifyFactory.register(Class clazz)](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyFactory.java) for each entity class that you're persisting. This should be done once (per JVM instance).

Comment: I have this in each entity the application is to persist\

Comment: Hmm.. What IDE do you use ? And how do you launch your application in it?

Comment: I had registered my class but I still got the error.

Comment: Same all, and i am using Spring Boot