# How to deploy GWT GAE applications on external server

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, tomcat, jetty

I Have an GWT+GAE application with nosql database that runs fine in Google App Engine and in eclipse + gwt plugin with embedded jetty server on development environment.
Now in production environment, for many causes, i have to deploy this application on an external self managed server like Tomcat or JBoss.
I follow with no luck many tutorials and tips&tricks like:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/LYySmvqdbO8

or [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231337/how-to-setup-gwt-for-tomcat) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848198/debug-gwt-application-with-tomcat-eclipse) [Link3](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/) [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657947/place-gwt-application-on-jetty) [Link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076527/no-api-environment-is-registered-for-this-thread-error-when-persisting-object)

When I deploy my application on an external server (i.e. tomcat or jetty) it starts correctly but when I do a call that uses database connection it gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:102)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:69)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.AsyncObjectifyImpl.query(AsyncObjectifyImpl.java:354)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl.query(ObjectifyImpl.java:207)
    at com.beoui.geocell.ObjectifyGeocellQueryEngine.query(ObjectifyGeocellQueryEngine.java:52)
    at com.beoui.geocell.GeocellManager.proximitySearch(GeocellManager.java:381)
```

How can I deploy to external servers like Tomcat, JBOSS or Jetty?
Or [it isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186947/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-run-an-google-app-engine-gwt-application-on-mac-os) at all?

My opinion is: whether the application runs correctly on eclipse embedded jetty, in some way is possible to configure an external jetty distribution to run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE comes with a [set of services](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/apis) which are basically big external systems hidden behind an API. Local dev server is just a Jetty with an embedded database and an API layer mimicking the production GAE. You can not use the dev server for production purposes - it was not made for this and has no concurrency and reliability features of production system.

If you want to run GAE code somewhere else then production GAE service, take a look at [AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/) or [CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf).

Also, most links that you provided deal with running GWT app on Tomcat/Jetty, but you have problems with AppEngine. [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) and [AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) are two separate technologies (which can work together, but it's not required).

Comment: I think that CapeDwarf solves my problems even if at now is an embrional distribution and there is few documentation. Now it gives me this error: `org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.DatastoreStatistics
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:167)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1026)`. Any suggenstions?